# Maven package signing or how you trust/verify Maven Central artifacts for integrity and authentity?

Tags: security, maven, maven-central

I come from C world to Java. In C most libraries are system from signed packages, from Open Source home page with .gpg signing or come from vendors through trusted sources.

In case of Java package distribution I investigate `.m2` directory and file content. There are no signing!

with empty `~/.m2/settings.xml` and minimal `pom.xml` I get:

```
$ mvn help:effective-settings
...
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/2.8.1/maven-javadoc-plugin-2.8.1.pom
```

So ever packages loaded from HTTP, not HTTPS! But ever with HTTPS you can get certificate for 100$ at GoDaddy.

How your team manage security with Maven packages?

Do you restrict your team with own Nexus installation where placed trusted/reviewed packages or forbid any Open Source packages/any external packages due to security issues?

**UPDATE** I found that some from our team put this source:

- http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

instead of:

- https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

To decrease server load and maintenance cost for SSL/TLS handshake most *free* Maven services provide both HTTP and HTTPS connection. For security it will be nice to close HTTP port at all, but who paid for CPU time of hosting companies...

Comment: "but who paid for CPU time of hosting companies" - As far as I know for most people the TLS performance hit is greatly overestimated, see: http://blog.haproxy.com/2011/09/16/benchmarking_ssl_performance/ . They get 2300 SSL transaction per second on an Intel Atom. You can get even better performance today with ECDSA keys and AES_GCM, the latter of which has hardware support on most modern CPUs.

Comment: I investigate performance issue and found that I wrong... Average .jar size is 500 KiB. 10 GB/s ~= 1 Gbyte/s, disk read about 50 Mbyte/s. So from cache you can get 2.000 pkg/s, from disk 100 pkg/s. So SSL seems not a limit...

Answer (score 0):

I read excellent blog posts:

http://softwaremavens.blogspot.com/2010/01/top-10-reasons-why-maven-sucksnot.html

and in comments I found link to:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Repository+Security

which lists incomplete plans to add security to repositories (page last touched at 2008!!).